# Android. User's finger enter into the view from outside of that view

Tags: android, view, motionevent, drag

Let's say that the user has started her finger motion towards some view on the screen.

How to detect:

1. The moment when the user's finger entered into the view from outside of that view?
2. The moment when the user finger will leave this view (if this gonna happen)?

(Attaching OnHoverListener to the View is not working)